# Retrieving Data in A NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a three column Table View populated by two NSMutableDictionaries which share the same keys (ie key | value1 | value2 ) with dict1(key,value1) and dict2(key,value2).
I want to manually enter data in the third column and create the key/value objects in dict2. But when I do that, my code picks the wrong key :S

Here's the code for the delegate :

```
 - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
if ([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"value2"])
   {   
    [dict2 setValue:anObject forKey:[[[aTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"key"] dataCellForRow:rowIndex] stringValue ]];
   }    
}
```

Any idea ?

EDIT : I want to complete my question : how can you retrieve the data displayed in a cell ?
I see no other way to use NSMutableDictionnaries with TableViews, because [dict allKeys] does not give the keys in the same order that the one that is used to display it ! And stocking a version of [dict allKeys] just seems redundant and stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this delegate function you're using is used for showing the data in the tableview with the format data source. It's used for setting, not retrieving.

You may use - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to set the data source for tableview.